# Write permission in windows phone 8 cocos2d-x

Tags: windows-phone-8, cocos2d-x

I have an application  in cocos2d-x where user adds data in text file an can delete the content whenever he wants

To create text file getWritablepath function is used to create file

```
std::string path = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getWritablePath() + "demo.txt";
FILE* file = fopen(path.c_str(), "a+");
```

To delete content.. Everything user wants apart from the content s/he deleted is copied in temp file and orignal file is removed and temp file is renamed

```
std::string path_temp = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getWritablePath() + "temp1.txt";
FILE* file_temp = fopen(path_temp.c_str(), "a+");
const char* break1 = "~";


for (int i=0;i< array1->count(); i++) {
    CCString *string=(CCString *)array1->objectAtIndex(i);
    const char* tmp1 = string->getCString();
    file = fopen(path_temp.c_str(), "a+");
    ifstream is;

    is.open (path_temp.c_str(), ios::binary| ios::ate );
    int length = is.tellg();
    is.close();
    cout<<"size by new"<<length;

    if(tmp2!=tmp1){

        if(length==0){

            fputs(tmp1, file_temp);
            fclose(file_temp);
        }
        else
        {
            fputs(break1,file_temp);
            fputs(tmp1, file_temp);
               fclose(file_temp);
        }


    }
}
array1->removeObjectAtIndex(tag);
remove(path.c_str());                       // This particular function remove rename   gives error as write permission denied
rename(path_temp.c_str(), path.c_str());
```

Above logic works correctly in android and ios

Remove, rename doesn't work in windows its throws error as write permission denied.
Application data is stored in isolated storage of windows phone.